# Transparent pixels rendering as black in fabric.js

Tags: three.js, png, webgl, fabricjs

I'm trying to load a .png image with some fully transparent pixels into a fabric.js canvas and they are loading as black pixels in the browser. How can I make them render as transparent pixels only

original image
[image]

in fabric.js
[image]

Comment: Not quite sure of the issue without some example code or a fiddle, but couldn't you just set `canvas.backgroundColor = "transparent"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas_input" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas_input = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_input');
        fabric.Image.fromURL("./trans2.png", function(img){
            canvas_input.add(img);
            canvas_input.renderAll();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this should work fine. Make sure you are serving the static files. You can use python -m simpleHTTPServer

Comment: Give the give some sort description of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually scaling down the image before loading on to the canvas which was giving this blackness in the transparent background. When I increased my scaling limit to the original image dimensions, it was working fine.